# Placeholders in Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot

Do you know if Spring Boot supports placeholders in `@ConfigurationProperties`?
When I set `spring.boot.admin.client.serviceUrl=http://${server.address}:${server.port}${server.context-path}` it would be bind to [AdminClientProperties](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-starter-client/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/config/AdminClientProperties.java) but Spring Boot doesn't replace placeholders.

I haven't found any information about this in documentation.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using? This was fixed in 1.2.0 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1301. I just tested it in 1.2.6 and the placeholder was resolved even when using a custom location: @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="props", locations="classpath:example.properties")

Comment: I use Spring Boot 1.2.5. As I understand in order to provide such behaviour I have to define locations attribute. How should I define locations when I use Spring Cloud Config additionally?

Answer (score 1):

I found in the javadoc of @ConfigurationProperties :

> - Note that contrary to {@code @Value}, SpEL expressions are not evaluated since property values are externalized.

This explains, why you only get the raw value.
I was really surprised to see that.

Comment: SpEl using #{...} and property placeholders using ${...} are two different things, so this doesn't answer the question.